# Mysql return matching users in subqueries

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to write one query to compare the results of multiple mysql subqueries, and return users that are in each query.

I have a that contains fantasy football stats for players.  To simplify, in this case there are 3 columns I'm using: player, points, year.

I'm looking to run a query that returns a list of players who finished in the top 50 (based on points) in both 2010 and 2011.

I've done lots of searching around on playing with subqueries, doing joins on one table, etc but am still coming up at a loss on how to approach this.

Comment: You should accept whichever answer helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT  a.player

FROM    (SELECT player FROM players WHERE Year = 2010 ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 50) a

        JOIN

        (SELECT player FROM players WHERE Year = 2011 ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 50) b
        ON a.player = b.player
```

Comment: Each subquery returns the top 50 players, and you join the two on the player (his name, id, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. I assumed that you calculate top50 based on sum of points and you have several entries for each player in each year.

```
select y2010.player 
from (
  select player, sum from (
    select st1.player player, sum(st1.points) sum from stats st1 where st1.year = 2010 group by st1.player order by sum desc
  ) t1 limit 50 offset 0
) y2010, (
  select player, sum from (
    select st1.player player, sum(st1.points) sum from stats st1 where st1.year = 2011 group by st1.player order by sum desc
  ) t1 limit 50 offset 0
) y2011
where y2010.player = y2011.player
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNION ALL`, this will get you the `Top 50` in both years and put them in the same result set, no joining required:

```
(
    select player, year, points 
    from players
    where year = 2010
    order by points desc
    limit 50
)
union all
(
    select player, year, points 
    from players
    where year = 2011
    order by points desc
    limit 50
);
```

Comment: What if the 50th person is tied with the 51st?

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly ambiguous whether you want:

- all players who finished in the top 50 in 2010, as well as all players who finished in the top 50 in 2011:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM   scores
  WHERE  year = 2010
     AND points >= (SELECT MIN(points) FROM (
                     SELECT   points
                     FROM     scores
                     WHERE    year = 2010
                     ORDER BY points DESC
                     LIMIT    50
                   ) t)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM   scores
  WHERE  year = 2011
     AND points >= (SELECT MIN(points) FROM (
                     SELECT   points
                     FROM     scores
                     WHERE    year = 2011
                     ORDER BY points DESC
                     LIMIT    50
                   ) t)
  ```
- all players who finished in the top 50 in *both* 2010 and 2011, in which case you'll need to further group the results:

  ```
  SELECT   player
  FROM     (
             -- query as above
           ) t
  GROUP BY player
  HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 2
  ```

Comment: If it's guaranteed that a player can only appear once in each year, you could replace `COUNT(DISTINCT year)` with the more performant `COUNT(*)`.